# Ignite Configuration 2.6-IGFS Speed--do backups/disk writes Asynchronously?

Tags: java, performance, ignite

I am working on performance tuning my ignite cluster as I scale horizontally.  My use case is files saved into IGFS.  Median size would be about 2 M, max size 120G, with a 95 percentile around 1 G.  Heavy skew towards smaller size.

My model is that it is OK to lose data, as every piece of data can be recovered with a performance hit.  However, I don't want to have my ignite cluster get corrupt if members go down, as refetching all the data would be a very bad day for my users (and by extension, me).

On the other hand, I want saves to be as fast as possible.  SO I am taking the approach that it's fine to evict data, and fine to loose some amount of data should a few nodes go down, as long as I don't lose more than 10% of my data in an outage.

I have a FileSystemConfiguration named "igfs" and I want it to lazy-persist to the DataStorageConfiguration also named "igfs".

To have some redundancy, I set up ignite to use 1 backup with the IgniteConfiguration.AtomicConfiguration.backup = 1.  I think that means that every entry in ignite writes to one duplicate.  However, I want that backup to happen ASYNCHRONOUSLY.  I can't find a way to do that for IGFS entries.  Is there a way?

Also, is there a way to set up igfs to lazy-write to the default persistence tier, which is disk based?  I really want to finish my writes from my client and have the data just in memory.  It can flush to disk in its own time.

```
<?xml version = .....
<beans ....


<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="marshaller">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller" />
    </property>

   <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="10000" />
   <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="10000" />
   <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
   <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="#{120*1000}"/>
   <property name="atomicConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.AtomicConfiguration">
              <property name="backups" value="1" />
        </bean>
   </property>

   <property name="fileSystemConfiguration" >
        <list>
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.FileSystemConfiguration">
                  <property name="name" value="igfs" />
                  <property name="blockSize" value="262144" />
                  <property name="bufferSize" value="262144" />
                  <property name="defaultMode" value="DUAL_ASYNC" />
                  <property name="dataCacheConfiguration" >
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                                <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true" />
                                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                                      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                                                <property name="maxMemorySize" value="#{10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
                                      </bean>
                                </property>
                                <property name="eagerTtl" value="true" />
                                <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                                     <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf"?
                                           <constructor-arg>
                                                 <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                                      <constructor-arg value="HOURS"/>
                                                      <constructor-arg value="15"/>
                                                 </bean>
                                           </constructor-arg>
                                     </bean>
                               </property>
                               <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                               <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true" />
                          </bean>
                  </property>
             </bean>
        </list>
   </property>
   <property name="communicationSpi">
       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
           <property name="messageQueueLimit" value="500"
       </bean>
   </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
               <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                              <property name="addresses">
                                   <list>
                                          <value>IP:47500..47509</value>
                                          <value>IP:47500..47509</value>
                                   </list>
                              </property>
                        </bean>
               </property>
          </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                   <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                        <list>
                              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                                    <property name="name" value="igfs" />
                                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                                    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true" />
                                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{35: * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />

                              </bean>
                        </list>
                   </property>
                  <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                             <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                             <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true" />
                             <property name="maxSize" value="#{35: * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
                  </property>
                  <property name="systemRegionMaxSize" value="#{6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
          </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup happend asynchronously by default. You need to specify `writeSynchronizationMode` to `SYNC` on `CacheConfiguration` to make it otherwise.

The largest speedup in your case should be setting `walMode` to `LOG_ONLY` on your `DataStorageConfiguration`.

Comment: Thank you!  The difference between BACKGROUND and LOG_ONLY for walMode seems subtle.  It ony does BACKGROUND for real if this IGNITE_WAL_MMAP is overridden to be false, right?  But what does that do?  I see that flag enables/disables mapped-byte-buffers, and I 1. Don't know how to change the settings to observe the behavior and 2. Don't know what the alternative to mapped byte buffers is and what the pros/cons would be.  Do you know?

Comment: BACKGROUND removes consistency guarantees in case of process crash, which is probably not something you want.

Comment: I only want to avoid having to delete my entire ignite cache's data store, I don't mind losing a small amount of data.  Does BACKGROUND really risk that, or just losing a little data?  My hardware is awful and I expect things to crash a lot, or cycle in and out of the ignite cluster.

Comment: I think that it may corrupt your whole persistent store, but I'm not sure about its failure modes. I'm not sure if there is something for "don't mind losing small amount". Maybe 3rd party store + writeBehind?